# Chunked encoding using python requests - Error 10054 connection forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests, http-status-code-301, chunked-encoding

I receive a Chunked Encoding Error when running my script using python requests, and I am wondering why I could be receiving this error.

When I do `resp.encoding` I get it back `None`

I am currently not using any SSL certification verification in my script and so I get Insecure Requests Warnings as well.

```
    for attachment in attachments:
     if attachment['type'] == 'Form':
        continue
      # create insertcursor row
      row = cursorPointData.newRow()
      pprint(attachments)

      for key in attachment:
        pprint(key)
        pprint(attachment[key])

        row.setValue(key, attachment[key])

    # Download file

      guid = attachment['guid']
      resp = requests.get(
        'https:...' + guid,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
        stream=True,
        verify=False
      )
     contentType = resp.headers['Content-Type']
     contentLength = int(resp.headers['content-length'])
     pprint('contentLength = ' + str(contentLength))
     extension = contentType.split('/')[1]
     filename = '{0}.{1}'.format(guid, extension)
     output_path = os.path.join(attachmentDir, filename)
     attachmentPath = os.path.join("filepath", filename)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush() #flush the data to file
                os.fsync(f.fileno()) #force the file write and free memory

    row.setValue('attachmentPath', attachmentPath)

    cursorPointData.insertRow(row)
del cursorPointData, row
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked in the Network tab of Chrome developer tools, and I was getting a status 200. However in Firefox developer tools, I got a 301 status: "Moved Permanently".

It turns out I was putting in the wrong url to the request and needed to change the url to the updated version it was redirecting to.

Found out you can use `response.history` in the python requests library to find any redirection issues.

Now,  I get back `utf-8` as the response encoding instead of none.

Leaving this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.